# filtro de busca sql - exceção

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, select

Olá!

Estou com dificuldade de desenvolver uma logica para uma busca no banco.

Preciso retornar do banco uma tabela com a lista de aluno matriculados com um determinado tipo de voucher.

Porém cada aluno pode ter N vouchers atribuídos a matrícula dele.

Pra exemplificar, fiz essa tabela de vouchers. Todos os alunos possuem o voucher A, porém preciso de um select que retorne os que possuem exclusivamente os do tipo A. Os alunos 002 e 003 não devem entrar na busca já que eles possuem o B e/ou C também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso?

Minha consulta está assim

```
SELECT P.COD_ALUNO, P.NOME, P.ID_TIPO_PESSOAS 
FROM TB_VOUCHER V
INNER JOIN TB_PESSOAS P ON P.COD_ALUNO = V.COD_ALUNO 
WHERE 
  V.TIPO_VOUCHER = 239 AND 
  V.COD_ALUNO IS NOT NULL AND 
  P.ID_TIPO_PESSOAS = 10
```

Comment: escreva ai na pergunta o select/from/where que já fez até agora

Comment: Pesquise pelos que tem voucher = A e utilizando a cláusula NOT EXISTS faça um subsect para o aluno com vouche <> A.

Comment: edita a pergunta e coloca a query completa lá, fica melhor pra visualizar

Comment: coloquei a consulta. sao duas tabelas que pego os alunos com voucher 239 e que estejam com matricula ativa

Answer (score 0):

Avalie se é isto o que deseja:

```
SELECT P.COD_ALUNO, P.NOME, P.ID_TIPO_PESSOAS 
FROM TB_VOUCHER V
INNER JOIN TB_PESSOAS P ON P.COD_ALUNO = V.COD_ALUNO 
WHERE 
  V.TIPO_VOUCHER = 239 AND 
  V.COD_ALUNO IS NOT NULL AND 
  P.ID_TIPO_PESSOAS = 10 AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TB_VOUCHER AUX WHERE AUX.COD_ALUNO = V.COD_ALUNO AND AUX.TIPO_VOUCHER <> 239)
```

Não corresponde exatamente à sua descrição mas, se interpretei corretamente, parece estar de acordo com o código postado.

Answer (score 0):

Júnior, segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando a claúsula *Having* com as funções *Min* e *Max*:

```
SELECT P.COD_ALUNO, P.NOME, P.ID_TIPO_PESSOAS 
FROM TB_PESSOAS P
INNER JOIN TB_VOUCHER V ON V.COD_ALUNO = P.COD_ALUNO 
WHERE 
  P.ID_TIPO_PESSOAS = 10 AND
  V.TIPO_VOUCHER = 239
GROUP BY P.COD_ALUNO, P.NOME, P.ID_TIPO_PESSOAS
HAVING
  MIN(V.TIPO_VOUCHER) = 'A' AND
  MAX(V.TIPO_VOUCHER) = 'A'
```

Nos casos em que só existir o tipo 'A', as funções Min e Max vão retornar 'A', e se existirem outros tipos uma das 2 funções vai retornar um valor diferente.

Espero que ajude